# Can't set text to hidden input

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set a text to input and then click on the hidden link (sounds maybe stupid but this is a workaround for another issue). So I've tried something like

```
WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id$='inputId']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';", element);
element.sendKeys(text);
```

I've also tried

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].setText(" + text + ")", element);
or "arguments[0].text="someText"
```

None of these work, test always ends with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is of an illegal type: $Proxy30
```

When I debug it, I can see that element is correctly found but I am getting this exception during execution of the script. So what am I doing wrong here?

P.S. How do I click on that link, do I have to use JS Executor too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In semi-solid browsers, you can even search for the element via JavaScript, just run this:

```
var elem = document.querySelector("input[id$='inputId']");
elem.value = "some text";
```

Also note the use of `value`. I haven't ever seen the `setText()` method or `text` attribute on an element, so maybe I am mistaken. But I'm sure that input values are set by the `value` attribute.

In WebDriver:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)webDriver;
js.executeScript(
    "document.querySelector(\"input[id$='inputId']\").value = '" + someText + "';");
```

Comment: I've seen it somewhere, probably was a dumb idea to try this method. Anyway, how do I use your code with WebDriver?I see just pure JavaScript

Comment: I thought you know how to execute any JS... Edited into the answer, try it out.

Comment: Sorry, it's friday and I have a quite big braindead:-)It works, thanks a lot.

Comment: @PetrMensik Note that this won't really work in lower versions of IE, we'd have to use the selenium's internal JS browserbot capabilities if you needed that.

Comment: Well, what is lower?I think our tests are running only on IE 8 and above

Comment: Good for you =). [According to this doc, `querySelector()` is supported in IE8 and above.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector)